# Unable to scan bluetooth device (5+) from core bluetooth

Tags: core-bluetooth

Unable to Scan bluetooth 5.42 device from Core bluetooth below is my code

```
internal func centralManager(
    _ central: CBCentralManager,
    didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
    advertisementData: [String: Any],
    rssi RSSI: NSNumber
) {        
    print(peripheral)
    guard let name = peripheral.name else { return }
    print(name)
    if !scannedDevices.contains(peripheral) {
        scannedDevices.append(peripheral)
    }
    self.scanListTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Does the method get called?  The peripheral name may be nil. Does the Light Blue app from the App Store find your peripheral?

Comment: Hi Paulw peripheral name is not nil. it is showing in iphone bluetooth setting screen.its bluetooth version is 5.42. can you suggest how i scan the same.

Comment: What about the other two questions I asked?

Comment: Does the method get called : YES

Comment: Does the Light Blue app from the App Store find your peripheral?: NO

Comment: Right, so set a breakpoint and step through it. From looking at your code it is likely that `peripheral.name` is nil although if Light Blue can’t find it then it is likely your peripheral is not advertising a GATT service and perhaps some other peripheral is being discovered.

Comment: Is your device Bluetooth Low Energy? Does it implement the GATT & everything ? Is it even advertising? What's your kind of device?